# How to extracts a string value from the line using awk and stores it in a variable

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm trying to extract the stock value from the line using awk and store it in the variable stock. Then, I attempt to decrease it by one and update the same position in the line. However, it seems that the updating process is not working properly.

If livros stock is 71, when function vender_livro() is called for that book title  the stock will change to 70 in livros.txt (Store Data).

- **The output of livros works, displays the rightline.**
- **The output of stock (stock=$(echo "$linha" | awk '{print $6}'))

  returns the right value.**
- **Decreasing the values from stock works ("stock=$(($stock - 1))").**

**Problem**:

> sed -i "s/$titulo[^ ]* $stock/$titulo $stock/" livros

Is not replacing the new value correctly.

The data inside books.txt is displayed in this order:

> "Author Title Description Genre NumPages Stock Price"

Function :>

```
    vender_livro() {
  echo "         -----------------"
  echo "         |   Sell Book    |"
  echo "         -----------------"
  read -p "Enter the title of the book to sell: " titulo

  if grep -q "$titulo" livros; then

    linha=$(grep "$titulo" livros)

    stock=$(echo "$linha" | awk '{print $6}')
    stock=$(($stock - 1))

    sed -i "s/$titulo[^ ]* $stock/$titulo $stock/" livros
    echo "Book sold successfully!"

  else
    echo "No book found in the database."
  fi

  echo
  read -p "Press Enter to continue" continue
  clear
```

}

Comment: Do you limit support to one-word authors, titles, descriptions, and genres?  Otherwise, how is the program supposed to recognize the boundaries between these?

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot do substantially the whole job via one `awk` pass?

Comment: please update the question with a sample set of lines from the file (eg, `head -4 filename`), the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) expected output

Comment: Please trying add some `echo`s to reveal values of `linha` and `stock` before line with `sed`. What should happen if user provide title which is substring of more than 1 line? Explain how your question is related to `ssh`, which is one of tags you have applied.

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before modification

```
stock=$(($stock - 1))

sed -i "s/$titulo[^ ]* $stock/$titulo $stock/" livros
```

After modification

```
sed -i -E "s/($titulo ([^ ]+ ){3})$stock/\1$((--stock))/" livros
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -i inplace \                                        # change livros.txt in place 
    -v title=$titulo '                                  # passing titulo variable as title    
    BEGIN{
        out = "No book found in the database"           # set default output if title not found
    }
    $1==title {                                         # if title found for example in first column
                                                        # or '$0 ~ tilte' looking for title anywhere  
        $6-=1                                           # decrease col 6 (stock)
        out = "Book sold successfully!"                 # set success output 
    }1                                                  # print all rows
    END{
        print out                                       # print output 
    }
  ' livros.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

The "expr" was missing, soo when trying do decrease the stock the var $stock was a string instead of int.

To replace the line in the file I change from sed to awk.

```
   # Decrease stock by one
    newStock=$(expr "$stock" - 1)



    # Update the stock value in the line using awk

    awk -v title="$titulo" -v newStock="$newStock" '{ if ($2 == title) { $6 = newStock } print }' livros > livros_temp && mv livros_temp livros
```